# Decomposing a Series in Python

Tags: python, windows

I have a series in python that looks as follows:

I want the split the series into users with Windows operating systems and those who are not using Windows operating systems.  Is there a way to do this in python 2.7.3? Thank you in advance.

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko)  Chrome/17.0.963.78 Safari/535.11
GoogleMaps/RochesterNY
Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; InfoPath.3)
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/534.52.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1.2 Safari/534.52.7
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/17.0.963.79 Safari/535.11
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/17.0.963.79 Safari/535.11
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/17.0.963.79 Safari/535.11
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:2.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0.1
Opera/9.80 (X11; Linux zbov; U; en) Presto/2.10.254 Version/12.00
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/17.0.963.79 Safari/535.11
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:10.0.2) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0.2
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.4; en-US; rv:1.9.2.27) Gecko/20120216 Firefox/3.6.27
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:10.0.2) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0.2
```

Comment: there is always a way, what have you tried?

Comment: I indented your sample "data" because it seems to make more sense that way, but I can't be sure because it's only slightly more comprehensible. Please explain more clearly what you mean by "I have a series". Is this data in a file or some data structure? Are the numbers part of the data? Why are the URLs (mostly) right-aligned? Why does the first URL have no number?

Comment: @MarceloCantos What URLs? All those lines are [user agent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) identifiers.

Comment: @poke: That's what I meant. And yes, I'm an idiot.

Answer (score 1):

As [user agent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) strings are not really standardized but browser vendors only follow each other’s example, the safest bet to recognize Windows clients is to simply check if the string “Windows” is included in it. You can easily check that using the `in` operator in Python.

For example to count the number of Windows clients, you could do something like this (where `lines` is a list of all those user agent strings):

```
numWindows = 0
for line in lines:
    if 'Windows' in line:
        numWindows += 1

print('{0} of {1} users are using Windows.'.format(numWindows, len(lines)))
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this, which is similar to @poke's answer, but since Tarek mentioned *separating*, so here it is separated into two lists:

```
windows = []
others = []

for line in lines:
    if 'Windows' in line:
         windows.append(line)
    else:
         others.append(line)

print('Windows: {} Others: {}'.format(len(windows),len(others))
```